# ASP.NET MVC custom json config file

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, razor, configuration-files

I have a json configuration file:

```
{
  "chat": {
    "host": "http://localhost:4555"
  }
}
```

Also I have created class :

```
public class ChatConf
{
    public String host { get; set; }
}
```

In my Startup file I'm doing this:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<ChatConf>(Configuration.GetSection("chat"));
```

The question is how can I get value of host in my main Layout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to include Microsoft.Extension.IOption in your controller to work with the IOption collection. Then you can access your class by adding it to the constructor of you controller.

[here](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/20/asp-net-core-step-by-step-guide-to-access-appsettings-json-in-web-project-and-class-library/) is a good explanation

Comment: Thank you for response. I have figured it out. just forget to post answer.